# Designing simple wrapper around sqlalchemy

Tags: python, design-patterns, sqlalchemy

I want to create a simple wrapper around sqlalchemy (python3.6) but I'am stuck at the moment where session and table classes mapped. What should I do now? Should DBManager be implemented to provide interaction with all tables (how to implement that correctly?) or it should return object that will interact with certain table/class? Not sure what approach is correct. Also first time working with ORM. Thank you for your time.

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]




from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import create_session, Session

from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base

class DBManager(metaclass=Singleton):
    def __init__(self, config_path=''):
        self._db_operator = None
        self._db_config = {}
        self._db_tables = {}

        self._error = ''

        if config_path:
            self.load_config(config_path)
            self.connect_to_database()

    def connect_to_database(self):
        self._clean()

        DB_USER = ''
        DB_PASS = ''
        DB_HOST = ''
        DATABASE = ''
        DB_PORT = 3306
        try:
            DB_USER = self._db_config['DB_USER']
            DB_PASS = self._db_config['DB_PASSWORD']
            DB_HOST = self._db_config['DB_HOST']
            DATABASE = self._db_config['DB_NAME']

        except Exception as e:
            pass

        connection_string = 'mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}?charset=utf8mb4'.format(DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_HOST, DB_PORT,
                                                                                 DATABASE)

        engine = create_engine(connection_string, echo=True)
        session = Session(engine)

        Base = automap_base()
        Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

        user = Base.classes.users
        article = Base.classes.article

        session.add(user(username='ohyeah'))
        session.commit()
```

Comment: What is `Singleton`?

Comment: @KlausD. is a metalcass for implementing singleton pattern

Comment: If you are using meta classes make sure it is top clear what they are doing and where to find the code. They can substantially change the behavior of a class.

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
    This class is wrapper class to connect to any database. This class exposes simple functions for developers
    to save and retrive small or large data.
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100,10)))

    engine_args = {"db_type": 'postgresql',
        "address":'Name:Port',
        "user": "pxxxxxx",
        "password": "",
       "db_name": "databasename" }
    or engine_args ='sqlite:///my_db.sqlite'

    con = Connector(kwargs)
      
    con.push_df('tablename',df,is_replace=True,schema='raw',dtype=self.dbcon.df_col_detect(df,True),chunksize=10**5)

    df = con.get_df_table('tablename')
    df = con.get_df_query('SELECT * FROM tablename')
    
    To work with transaction do below code
    below code will automatically commit once transaction successful or rollback if any exception happens.
    It will close connection in any situation.
    con.init_engine()
    with con.engine.begin() as conn:
        response = con.exec_query(_query,_transaction_connection=conn):
        con.push_df('tablename',df,is_replace=True,schema='czuc',con=conn,method='postgrescopy')
    con.engine.dispose()
    if response.cursor:
        result = response.fetchone()
    else:
        result = response.rowcount
    

    """

import math
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine,text

from functools import wraps
import datetime
from io import StringIO
import csv


class Connector(object): 

   

def __init__(self, engine_args, logger=None):
    
    self.logger = logger
    self.engine_args = engine_args

    if(type(engine_args)==str):
        self.connection_string = engine_args
    else:
        self.connection_string = "{db_type}://{user}:{password}@{address}/{db_name}".format(**self.engine_args)


   

def init_engine(self,echo=False, **kwargs):

    
    
    kwargs['echo']=echo
    
    
    if self.logger:
        self.logger.debug("initiating engine with these options {}".format(kwargs))
        
                
    
    self.engine = create_engine(self.connection_string, **kwargs)
    
    if self.logger:
        if(type(self.engine_args)==str):
        
            self.logger.info('initiated engine with {}'.format(self.engine))
        else:        
        
            self.logger.info('initiated engine on address: {} with database: {} username: {}'.format(self.engine_args['address'],
                                                                                    self.engine_args['db_name'],
                                                                                    self.engine_args['user']))



def __remove_non_ascii(self, text):
    
    if isinstance(text, (pd.Timestamp, float, int)):
        return text
    if isinstance(text, (datetime.datetime, float, int)):
        return text
    if pd.isnull(text):
        return np.nan
    return ''.join(i for i in text if ord(i) < 128)


def __remove_non_ascii_df(self, df) -> pd.DataFrame:
   
    for colmn in df.columns:
        df[colmn] = df[colmn].apply(self.__remove_non_ascii)
    return df

def __psql_insert_copy(self,table, conn, keys, data_iter):
   
    # gets a DBAPI connection that can provide a cursor
    dbapi_conn = conn.connection
    with dbapi_conn.cursor() as cur:
        s_buf = StringIO()
        writer = csv.writer(s_buf)
        writer.writerows(data_iter)
        s_buf.seek(0)

        columns = ', '.join('"{}"'.format(k) for k in keys)
        if table.schema:
            table_name = '{}.{}'.format(table.schema, '"'+table.name+'"')
        else:
            table_name = '"'+table.name+'"'
        
        
        
        sql = 'COPY {} ({}) FROM STDIN WITH CSV'.format(
            table_name, columns)
        
        cur.copy_expert(sql=sql, file=s_buf)


def __write_df(self, table_name, df, **kwargs):
    """
    This is private function to class. This gets called by other public functions only.
    This function write dataframe to database by calling df.to_sql function
    param: table_name: Table where data to be saved in database
    param: df: This is DataFrame object
    param:**kwargs : This accepts any additional parameters needs to be passed to df.to_sql function
    """
    conn = self.engine
    if 'con' in kwargs.keys():
        conn = kwargs['con']
        kwargs.pop('con', None)

    index = False
    if 'index' in kwargs.keys():
        index =   kwargs['index'] 
        kwargs.pop('index',None)  
    
    df.to_sql(table_name, con=conn, index=index, **kwargs)
    
    return True



def __write_split_df(self, table_name, dfs, **kwargs):

   

    self.__write_df(table_name, dfs[0], **kwargs)

    if self.logger:
        self.logger.info("Pushed {} rows in table : {}".format(len(dfs[0]), table_name))

    kwargs.pop('if_exists', None)
    for df in dfs[1:]:
        self.__write_df(table_name, df, if_exists='append', **kwargs)

        if self.logger:
            self.logger.info("Pushed {} rows in table : {}".format(len(df), table_name))
    return True



def __split_df(self, df, chunksize):

      

    chunk_count = int(math.ceil(len(df) / chunksize))
    return np.array_split(df, chunk_count)


def __df_cleanup(self, df):

    

    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("(", "")
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(")", "")
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("%", "per")
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r"\\t","")
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r"\\n","")
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r"\\r","")
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r"\t","")
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r"\n","")
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r"\r","")

    df = self.__remove_non_ascii_df(df)
    # DF=DF.fillna(np.nan,inplace=True)
    #remove special char from data.
    df.replace(to_replace=[r"\\t|\\n|\\r|'|\t|\n|\r"], value=[""], regex=True, inplace=True) 

    return df

@staticmethod
def df_col_detect(dfparam:pd.DataFrame, is_all_data_string) -> dict:
    
    
    dtypedict = {}
    
    for i, j in zip(dfparam.columns, dfparam.dtypes):
        
        if (is_all_data_string):
            if (i == 'itec_date'):
                dtypedict.update({i: sqlalchemy.types.DateTime()})
            else:

                dtypedict.update({i: sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR()})
        else:

            if "object" in str(j):
                dtypedict.update({i: sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR()})
            if "date" in str(j):
                dtypedict.update({i: sqlalchemy.types.DateTime()})
            if "float" in str(j):
                dtypedict.update({i: sqlalchemy.types.Float()})
            if "int" in str(j):
                dtypedict.update({i: sqlalchemy.types.INT()})
    return dtypedict


def __check_engine(func):
    
    """
    This is private Decorating function. Its checks for engine class attribute. If not found then it calls 
    init_engine function.
    """
    @wraps(func)
    
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        if not hasattr(args[0], 'engine'):
        
            if 'use_batch_mode' in kwargs.keys():
                args[0].init_engine(use_batch_mode=kwargs['use_batch_mode'])
                
            else:
                args[0].init_engine()
                
        kwargs.pop('use_batch_mode',None)   
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner

@__check_engine
def push_df_large(self, table_name, df, is_replace=False, chunksize=10 ** 5,call_df_cleanup=False,method=None,schema=None, **kwargs):

    """
    This function pushes large datasets to database. It has functionality of spliting dataframes.
    :param table_name: Table to save data.
    :param df: Dataframe to be saved in database.
    :param is_replace: Pass false if you want to append data into existing table. Pass True if you want to create or replace
                        table with new data.
    :Param call_df_cleanup: If True it will call function to clean up df like remove non ascii characters from data also remove 
    any special characters like tabs or new line 
    :param chunksize: Specify the number of rows in each batch to be written at a time. By default, be default only 100000 rows witten in batch.
    :param **kwargs: This function calls df.to_sql function internally, any additional parameters need to be passed, pass as key and value
    like push_df_large(table_name, df, is_replace=False, chunksize=10 ** 5,schema='raw',dtype=df_col_detect(df,True),use_batch_mode=True)
    dtype and schema are additional parameters which will be passed to df.to_sql fuction as **kwargs
    :return : True or False
    :param: method :  default None
            values accepted 'postgrescopy' or None or 'multi'
            Controls the SQL insertion clause used:
            'postgrescopy' : When insert data in postgresql or postgressql flavour like redshift. This is very fast insert method for Postgres database
            None : Uses standard SQL INSERT clause (one per row).
            'multi': Pass multiple values in a single INSERT clause.
            
        con : Assign value only when you want to maintain transaction
              example : 
                con.init_engine()
                with con.engine.begin() as conn:
                    response = con.exec_query(_query,_transaction_connection=conn):
                    con.push_df('tablename',df,is_replace=True,schema='czuc',con=conn,method='postgrescopy')
                con.engine.dispose()
                if response.cursor:
                    result = response.fetchone()
                else:
                    result = response.rowcount
            
        
        schema : string, optional
        Specify the schema (if database flavor supports this). If None, use default schema.

        index : bool, default True
        Write DataFrame index as a column. Uses index_label as the column name in the table.

        index_label : string or sequence, default None
        Column label for index column(s). If None is given (default) and index is True, then the index names are used. A sequence should be given if the DataFrame uses MultiIndex.

        chunksize : int, optional
        Rows will be written in batches of this size at a time. By default, all rows will be written at once.

        dtype : dict, optional
        Specifying the datatype for columns. The keys should be the column names and the values should be the SQLAlchemy types or strings for the sqlite3 legacy mode.
        :return : True or False
        use_batch_mode : Optional. Accept values as True or False 
        This is to initiate db engine with use_batch_mode option, if it is not initiated earlier.
        Please read SQLAlchemy's create_engine() documentation where to use use_batch_mode. 
        
    """
    if df.empty:
        raise Exception ("Error : Empty DataFrame.")

    if df.columns.duplicated().any():
        raise Exception ("Error : Duplicate columns in DataFrame.")
    
    
    dispose_engine = True        
    if 'con' in kwargs.keys():
        dispose_engine = False
    
    dfsize = chunksize

    if (is_replace):
        if_exists = 'replace'
    else:
        if_exists = 'append'

    kwargs['schema'] = schema

    if call_df_cleanup:
        df = self.__df_cleanup(df)

    table_name = table_name.replace("'", "").replace('"', '').lower()

    status = False

    if dfsize is None:
        dfsize = 10 ** 5

    kwargs.pop('chunksize', None)

    if not method == None:
        if method =='postgrescopy':
            method = self.__psql_insert_copy
        
        kwargs['method'] = method
    
    s = time.time()
    if len(df) > dfsize:

        dfs = self.__split_df(df, dfsize)
        status = self.__write_split_df(table_name, dfs, if_exists=if_exists, **kwargs)
        if self.logger:
            self.logger.info("Total {} rows pushed in table : {} within: {}s".format(len(df), table_name,
                                                                                round(time.time() - s, 4)))

    else:

        status = self.__write_df(table_name, df, if_exists=if_exists, chunksize=dfsize, **kwargs)
        if self.logger:
            self.logger.info("Pushed {} rows in table : {} within: {}s".format(len(df), table_name,
                                                                                round(time.time() - s, 4)))

    
    #if self.logger:
        #self.logger.info('Pushed name: {} dataframe shape: {} within: {}s'.format(table_name,
                                                                                 #df.shape,
                                                                                 #round(time.time() - s, 4)))
    if dispose_engine:
        self.__db_dispose()
    return status



@__check_engine
def push_df(self, table_name, df, is_replace=False, call_df_cleanup=False, method=None,schema=None, **kwargs):

    """
        This function pushes datasets to database.
        :param table_name: Table to save data.
        :param df: Dataframe to be saved in database.
        :param is_replace: Pass false if you want to append data into existing table. Pass True if you want to create or replace
                            table with new data.
        :Param call_df_cleanup: If True it will call function to clean up df like remove non ascii characters from data also remove 
        any special characters like tabs or new line 
        :param **kwargs: This function calls df.to_sql function internally, any additional parameters need to be passed, pass as key and value
        like push_df(table_name, df, is_replace=False, chunksize=10 ** 5,schema='raw',dtype=df_col_detect(df,True),use_batch_mode=True)
        chunksize ,dtype and schema are additional parameters which will be passed to df.to_sql fuction as **kwargs
        
        :param: method :  default None
            values accepted 'postgrescopy' or None or 'multi'
            Controls the SQL insertion clause used:
            'postgrescopy' : When insert data in postgresql or postgressql flavour like redshift. This is very fast insert method for Postgres database
            None : Uses standard SQL INSERT clause (one per row).
            'multi': Pass multiple values in a single INSERT clause.
            
        con : Optional, Assign value only when you want to maintain transaction
              example : 
                con.init_engine()
                with con.engine.begin() as conn:
                    response = con.exec_query(_query,_transaction_connection=conn):
                    con.push_df('tablename',df,is_replace=True,schema='czuc',con=conn,method='postgrescopy')
                con.engine.dispose()
                if response.cursor:
                    result = response.fetchone()
                else:
                    result = response.rowcount
            
        
        schema : string, optional
        Specify the schema (if database flavor supports this). If None, use default schema.

        index : bool, default True
        Write DataFrame index as a column. Uses index_label as the column name in the table.

        index_label : string or sequence, default None
        Column label for index column(s). If None is given (default) and index is True, then the index names are used. A sequence should be given if the DataFrame uses MultiIndex.

        chunksize : int, optional
        Rows will be written in batches of this size at a time. By default, all rows will be written at once.

        dtype : dict, optional
       
        
        use_batch_mode : Optional. Accept values as True or False 
        This is to initiate db engine with use_batch_mode option, if it is not initiated earlier.
        Please read SQLAlchemy's create_engine() documentation where to use use_batch_mode. 
        
    """

    if df.empty:
        raise Exception ("Error : Empty DataFrame.")
    
    if df.columns.duplicated().any():
        raise Exception ("Error : Duplicate columns in DataFrame.")
    
    dispose_engine = True        
    if 'con' in kwargs.keys():
        dispose_engine = False
    
    if (is_replace):
        if_exists = 'replace'
    else:
        if_exists = 'append'
    
    kwargs['schema'] = schema
    
    if call_df_cleanup:
        df = self.__df_cleanup(df)

    table_name = table_name.replace("'", "").replace('"', '').lower()

    # Format the Dataframe in preparation

    # hit it up

    status = False

    if not method == None:
        if method =='postgrescopy':
            method = self.__psql_insert_copy
        
        kwargs['method'] = method

    s = time.time()
    status = self.__write_df(table_name, df, if_exists=if_exists, **kwargs)

    

    if self.logger:
        self.logger.info("Pushed {} rows in table : {} within: {}s".format(len(df), table_name,
                                                                                round(time.time() - s, 4)))
    if dispose_engine:
        self.__db_dispose()
    return status






@__check_engine
def get_df_large_table(self, table_name, **kwargs)-> pd.DataFrame:

    """
    This function performce select * from table , with default 100000 rows of batch reading
   
    Given a table name and a SQLAlchemy connectable, returns a DataFrame. This function does not support DBAPI connections.

    Parameters
    table_name : str

        Name of SQL table in database.  
    con : SQLAlchemy connectable or str

        A database URI could be provided as as str.  
        SQLite DBAPI connection mode not supported.  
    schema : str, default None

        Name of SQL schema in database to query (if database flavor  
        supports this). Uses default schema if None (default).  
    index_col : str or list of str, optional, default: None

        Column(s) to set as index(MultiIndex).  
    coerce_float : bool, default True

        Attempts to convert values of non-string, non-numeric objects (like  
        decimal.Decimal) to floating point. Can result in loss of Precision.  
    parse_dates : list or dict, default None

        - List of column names to parse as dates.  
        - Dict of `{column_name: format string}` where format string is  
        strftime compatible in case of parsing string times or is one of  
        (D, s, ns, ms, us) in case of parsing integer timestamps.  
        - Dict of `{column_name: arg dict}`, where the arg dict corresponds  
        to the keyword arguments of :func:`pandas.to_datetime`  
        Especially useful with databases without native Datetime support,  
        such as SQLite.  
    columns : list, default None

        List of column names to select from SQL table.  
    chunksize : int, default None

        If specified, returns an iterator where `chunksize` is the number of  
        rows to include in each chunk.  
    Returns
    DataFrame

        A SQL table is returned as two-dimensional data structure with labeled  
        axes.
     **kwargs : Any aditional parameter
    """
    

    s = time.time()
    if 'chunksize' not in kwargs.keys():
        kwargs['chunksize'] = 10 ** 5
    dfs = pd.read_sql_table(table_name, self.engine, **kwargs)

    try:
        df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0)
    except ValueError:  # No objects to concetenate. dfs is a generator object so has no len() property!
        if self.logger:
            self.logger.warning("No objects to concetenate on table_name: {}".format(table_name))
        return None

    length = 0
    if df is not None:
        length = len(df)
    if self.logger:
        self.logger.info('fetched {} rows from  {} within: {}'.format(length,table_name,                                                                                      
                                                                                  round(time.time() - s, 4)))
    self.__db_dispose()
    return df



@__check_engine
def get_df_table(self, table_name, **kwargs)-> pd.DataFrame:

    """
    This function performce select * from table , with default brining all rows at once
    Parameters
    table_name : str

        Name of SQL table in database.  
    con : SQLAlchemy connectable or str

        A database URI could be provided as as str.  
        SQLite DBAPI connection mode not supported.  
    schema : str, default None

        Name of SQL schema in database to query (if database flavor  
        supports this). Uses default schema if None (default).  
    index_col : str or list of str, optional, default: None

        Column(s) to set as index(MultiIndex).  
    coerce_float : bool, default True

        Attempts to convert values of non-string, non-numeric objects (like  
        decimal.Decimal) to floating point. Can result in loss of Precision.  
    parse_dates : list or dict, default None

        - List of column names to parse as dates.  
        - Dict of `{column_name: format string}` where format string is  
        strftime compatible in case of parsing string times or is one of  
        (D, s, ns, ms, us) in case of parsing integer timestamps.  
        - Dict of `{column_name: arg dict}`, where the arg dict corresponds  
        to the keyword arguments of :func:`pandas.to_datetime`  
        Especially useful with databases without native Datetime support,  
        such as SQLite.  
    columns : list, default None

        List of column names to select from SQL table.  
    chunksize : int, default None

        If specified, returns an iterator where `chunksize` is the number of  
        rows to include in each chunk.  
    Returns
    DataFrame

        A SQL table is returned as two-dimensional data structure with labeled  
        axes.
     **kwargs : Any aditional parameter
    """
   

    s = time.time()
    kwargs.pop('chunksize', None)
    df = pd.read_sql_table(table_name, self.engine, **kwargs)

    length = 0
    if df is not None:
        length = len(df)
    if self.logger:
        self.logger.info('fetched {} rows from  {} within: {}'.format(length,table_name,                                                                                      
                                                                                  round(time.time() - s, 4)))
    self.__db_dispose()
    return df


@__check_engine
def exec_query(self, _query,_transaction_connection=None,**kwargs):
    
    
    if self.logger:
        self.logger.info('running query: "{}"'.format(_query))
    _query = text(_query)
    result = None
    if _transaction_connection is not None:
        con = _transaction_connection
        result = con.execute(_query)
    else:
        
        if( type(self.engine)==sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine):
            with self.engine.connect() as con:
                response = con.execute(_query)
                if response.cursor:
                    result = response.fetchone()
                else:
                    result = response.rowcount
        else:
            """Below work around is for SQLite if some how we use native sqlite engine for excute query"""
            result = self.engine.execute(_query)
    
    

    

    if _transaction_connection is None:
        self.__db_dispose()
    
            

    return result



@__check_engine
def get_df_query(self, _query,sqlite_text_factory=None,**kwargs) -> pd.DataFrame:

    """
            This function performce any query on database. Any DML query
            
                    
            def read_sql_query(sql, con, index_col=None, coerce_float=True, params=None, parse_dates=None, chunksize: None=None)
    Read SQL query into a DataFrame.

    Returns a DataFrame corresponding to the result set of the query string. Optionally provide an index_col parameter to use one of the columns as the index, otherwise default integer index will be used.

    Parameters
    sql : str SQL query or SQLAlchemy Selectable (select or text object)
    :param sqlite_text_factory: This is to work around for sqlite database to avoid exception like (sqlite3.OperationalError) Could not decode to UTF-8.
                                        Pass value as bytes incase of above error. sqlite_text_factory = bytes
            
        SQL query to be executed.  
    con : SQLAlchemy connectable, str, or sqlite3 connection

        Using SQLAlchemy makes it possible to use any DB supported by that  
        library. If a DBAPI2 object, only sqlite3 is supported.  
    index_col : str or list of str, optional, default: None

        Column(s) to set as index(MultiIndex).  
    coerce_float : bool, default True

        Attempts to convert values of non-string, non-numeric objects (like  
        decimal.Decimal) to floating point. Useful for SQL result sets.  
    params : list, tuple or dict, optional, default: None

        List of parameters to pass to execute method.  The syntax used  
        to pass parameters is database driver dependent. Check your  
        database driver documentation for which of the five syntax styles,  
        described in PEP 249's paramstyle, is supported.  
        Eg. for psycopg2, uses %(name)s so use params={'name' : 'value'}.  
    parse_dates : list or dict, default: None

        - List of column names to parse as dates.  
        - Dict of `{column_name: format string}` where format string is  
        strftime compatible in case of parsing string times, or is one of  
        (D, s, ns, ms, us) in case of parsing integer timestamps.  
        - Dict of `{column_name: arg dict}`, where the arg dict corresponds  
        to the keyword arguments of :func:`pandas.to_datetime`  
        Especially useful with databases without native Datetime support,  
        such as SQLite.  
    chunksize : int, default None

        If specified, return an iterator where `chunksize` is the number of  
        rows to include in each chunk.  
    Returns
    DataFrame 
    """

    

    if self.logger:
        self.logger.info('running query: "{}"'.format(_query))

    s = time.time()
    if sqlite_text_factory is None:
        con = self.engine
    else:
        con = self.engine.raw_connection()
        con.connection.text_factory = sqlite_text_factory
    
    result = pd.read_sql_query(_query, con=con)
    length = 0
    if result is not None:
        
        length = len(result)
    if self.logger:
        self.logger.info('Finished running query with rows fetched {} within: {}'.format(
                                                                                  length,
                                                                                  round(time.time() - s, 4)))
   
    self.__db_dispose()
    return result
    
def __db_dispose(self):

   
    
    if( type(self.engine)==sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine):
        
        self.engine.dispose()
```